# sqlite insert duplicate entries

Tags: java, sqlite

I have a problem while inserting data in sqlite database.i created a table with  3 columns studentid,studentname and studentmarks.when i insert same marks for two different students it doesn't insert duplicate entery.How to solve this problem that it will accept duplicate entries on student name and student marks.thanks

Comment: Can you show your java function and SQL insert?

Comment: SQLite *will* persist all committed data and it *will* complain if a DML operation failed, so let's consider some possibilities: - 2nd data actually in database - 2nd data never inserted (incorrect program logic) - 2nd data not committed (transaction rolled back) - 2nd data replaced 1st data (using REPLACE, not INSERT) - an ignored/suppressed exception occurred (oops!).

Answer (score 3):

Since you have a student id there is no need to have a student name.  The table should have a course ID/Name column to associate a specific mark with a student and course.

Basically you want three tables:

```
Student (ID, Name)
Course (ID, Name)
Mark (studentID, courseID, studentMark)
```

This is called `third normal form`.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form

However, if you want just one table for your database, then you still must add course id and/or name to the table and make sure that the primary key include student id and course id.

Comment: A very good anwser. The problem is probabaly caused by some unique constraints like Primary Key on the table.

Answer (score 0):

You might have created the table with a primary key as StudentID. In that case, you can not insert multiple rows for a single Students marks. You will need to re-create the table removing restrictions like primary key/unique values for StudentID

You should also create a separate table for `Students`, with a primary key (`Student ID`) in which you only insert student data (each row represents a single student). 
Then create a table for Student_marks in which the relation of Student to Marks is One-To-Many, meaning that multiple rows in `Students_Marks` belong to a single row in `Students` table

Answer (score 0):

Check whether there's an Unique constraint on marks column/or if u have set marks as primary key if either of the above case is true you should drop unique constraint/primary key to make your code work as you expect (drop index  index_name on table_name) .